# Actionscript 3 how to duplicate a symbol onto the next frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im a total beginner at using AS3. I want to know is how does one duplicate a symbol and make it appear in the next frame.

example: when the user clicks on the symbol in that frame, the same symbol will appear in the next frame. If it is not possible then how does one move that symbol to the next frame.

Thank You in advance for answering.

Comment: How do you create your first symbol ?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably avoid to use timeline keyframe to achieve this kind of thing. However, if you really need to do it this way, here what I would do :

First, make sure the MovieClip you want to clone has ActionScript linkage.

Then:

```
my_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick)

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var m:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
    var c:Class = Object(m).constructor;
    var clone:MovieClip = new c() as MovieClip;
    gotoAndStop(2);
    addChild(clone);
}
```

This will add the clone to the stage, so if you go back to frame 1, you'll see the clone. There's no way to add an object to a specific timeline frame. If you want to achieve such a thing, you have to target a container on frame 2 and add to clone to the container.

something like this :

```
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var m:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
    var c:Class = Object(m).constructor;
    var clone:MovieClip = new c() as MovieClip;
    gotoAndStop(2);
    myContainerOnframe2.addChild(clone);
 }
```